# How can I use material icon in the web page

Tags: html, css, google-material-icons

I added

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

to `index.html`

but I can't show the icon on the web page it shows the icon name as a string.

I tried

```
<span class="material-icons-outlined">
  done
</span>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Change class from "material-icons-outlined" to "material-icons"

Comment: I did it but it does not work

Answer (score 4):

You can show Material icons on the web page using this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>

<i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">cloud</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:60px;color:red;">cloud</i>

</body>
</html>
```

**Example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">cloud</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:60px;color:red;">cloud</i>
```

Comment: Yes, it works thanks a lot.  Very nice answer and what I was looking for.